# Define a custom string wrapper symbol

Tags: bash, curl, string

I need to post to Slack with a `curl` REST call like this:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#deploybots", "username": "${GIT_BRANCH}-BOT", "text": "Message --> ${1}", "icon_emoji": ":${EMOJI}:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/...
```

The problem lies within the payload argument: since everything is wrapped inside single-quotes, the variables are not eval'd.

Is there an alternative solution to do an ugly mess which is wrap the payload argument inside double-quotes and then escape all the double-quotes within?

Thanks!

Comment: Slap the `data` into a temporary file, and use `curl -X post --data-urlencode payload@/path/to/file`?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of temporary files, but will do if no better ideas come in. Thanks!

Comment: Pass a string to curl and build it with a printf....

Answer (score 3):

Use a temporary file:

```
scratch="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f "$scratch"' EXIT
cat > "$scratch" << EOF
{
  "channel": "#deploybots",
  "username":  "${GIT_BRANCH}-BOT", 
  "text": "Message --> ${1}", 
  "icon_emoji": ":${EMOJI}:"
}
EOF
curl -X POST --data-urlencode payload@"$scratch" https://hooks.slack.com/[...]
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of temporary files, but will do if no better ideas come in. Thanks!

Comment: Also works with a process substitution (on `cat`) in `bash` if a temporary file doesn't feel right.

Comment: Or just store the here-doc in a variable: `data=$(cat <<EOF` ... then on separate lines `EOF` and `)`